# Unable to click and send parameters in mvc4 actionlink

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

I am creating link one button and when the users clicks on link button i am calling partial view. I want to have click event of Actionlink button and send parameters in actionlink but i am facing problems. I am not able to send parameters and click event. I am using class selector for click even as below.
This is my actionlink button.

```
@foreach (var group in Model.records)
 {
  <tr>
  <td>@Html.ActionLink(@group.clientId.ToString(),"",new { @clientId =@group.clientId.ToString(),@class ="delete" },null)</td>
  </tr>
 }
```

This is my jquery code.

```
  $('.delete').click(function (id) {
                alert(1);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: { clientId: id },
                    url: '/DocumentVerification/detailsbyClientId',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#detailsbyclientId').html("");
                        $('#detailsbyclientId').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
```

At present when i click on actionlink below url will be there in browser.
Can anyone suggest me where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
http://localhost:62777/DocumentVerification?clientId=1006&class=delete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ActionLink()` is wrong and you adding the class name as a route value. But there is no need to use `ActionLink()` (and if you do then you need to cancel the default redirect). In addition, the `id` parameter in your method is the event object (not a value)

Change you html to

```
<a href="#" data-id="@group.clientId" class="delete">@group.clientId</a>
```

and the script to

```
$('.delete').click(function (id) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { clientId: id },
        url: '@Url.Action("detailsbyClientId", "DocumentVerification")', // don't hard code url's
        success: function (data) {
            // $('#detailsbyclientId').html(""); not required
            $('#detailsbyclientId').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

or more simply

```
var url = '@Url.Action("detailsbyClientId", "DocumentVerification")';
$('.delete').click(function (id) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#detailsbyclientId').load(url, { clientId: id });
});
```

Comment: When i click on link button nothing happens and this will be the url http://localhost:62777/DocumentVerification/Index#

Comment: Impossible. Your doing something else wrong. (`href="#"` cannot generate that url - that could only be generated using your current `ActionLink()` and only if the page your in was generated by the `Index()` method of `DocumentVerificationController`

Comment: Nowhere i given Index as actionmethod above. still getting same. I will look this again

Comment: Put a break point on your script and debug it. Is it even being hit? Have you installed jquery? Is the script at the bottom of the page, or wrapped in `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 0):

Because you mixed the **route values object** and **html attributes object** to a single object and passed that to the method as a single parameter. Your current call matches with the below overload

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

So your single object will go to the routeValues parameter and you are passing `null` for the fourth param(`htmlAttributes`)

Pass the html attributes as a seperate parameter. You can also specify the url you want to call for the ajax call as the link href.Here i am using another overload where i specify the action name and the controller name along with the route values.

```
@Html.ActionLink(group.clientId,"detailsByClientId","DocumentVerification"
                       ,new { clientId =group.clientId}, new {@class ="delete" })
```

This will generate the link with href value like `"/DocumentVerification/DetailsByClientId?clientId=25"`and css class `delete`

Now since the clientId is in the query string, you can simply use the clicked item's url (href value) for your ajax call.

```
$('.delete').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $.post($(this).attr("href"),function(data){
        $('#detailsbyclientId').html(data);                   
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes now click event is working but i am not able to recieve parameter(clientId)